# Return a shared_ptr from a class C++

Tags: c++

I have a question which has to do with returning a shared pointer from a class.
Part of my class looks like this:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<IBaseInterface> IBaseInterfaceSP;
...

IBaseInterfaceSP getMyInterface()
   {
      m_spBase = std::make_shared<IBaseInterfaceSP>( m_derivedInterface);
      return m_spBase;
   }
```

where both `m_derivedInterface` and `m_spBase` are private members of my class, i.e:

```
private:

   IBaseInterfaceSP m_spBase ;

   DerivedInterface m_derivedInterface;
```

Also, `DerivedInterface` inherits from `IBaseInterfaceSP`.

`getInterface` is a public function of my class.

Is this the right way to return a pointer from my class? Will there be any problems with slicing or anything similar?

P.S. I am sorry if something is unclear ( I am not allowed to post all the code here in public, only some parts), if so, just let me know.

Comment: Seems sort of broken to me.  How come m_xmlInterface isn't, itself, an IConfigInterfaceSP within the class?  That makes it appear that there are two different owners responsible for deleting the same object.

Comment: About that post-scriptum: we (the SO C++ community) generally don't want more code, but less. While you're waiting for an answer, consider reading [mcve] ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do - is this some kind of caching/lazy initialization, where you want to store m_spConfig internally, and return it if it exists (this is not what the code is currently doing, but kind of rings this bell for me)? Or something else entirely.
The code as written should work, but any subsequent calls to getInterface will construct a new IConfigInterface, which seems unlikely to be the intended effect.

Comment: This does indeed slice - you're creating a new `IConfigInterface` from `m_xmlInterface` every time the function is called, giving up ownership of the previous one. I'm guessing that this is not what you want, but I also can't guess what it is that you do want.

Comment: @molbdnilo This has nothing to do with slicing: slicing is when an instance of a derived class is copied into an instance of a base class, thus losing the "derived part". There is no slicing involved here.

Comment: @fkorsa `std::make_shared<IConfigInterface>(m_xmlInterface)` creates an `IConfigInterface`, copying `m_xmlInterface` into it. I think that fits your description of slicing pretty well.

Comment: @molbdnilo My bad, I didn't read the question carefully enough, and didn't see that ReadInterface inherited from IConfigInterface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see several problems with this code.

**1. Lazy initialization**

Each time you call getInterface, you create a new instance of your IBaseInterface class. As a user of your class, I would not expect this behavior from a method called "get".

I guess you wanted to implement lazy initialization, in which case you would do it like this:

```
IBaseInterfaceSP getInterface()
{
    if (!m_spBase)
    {
        m_spBase= std::make_shared<IBaseInterface>( m_derivedInterface );
    }
    return m_spBase;
}
```

**2. Naming conventions**

You are instantiating a class called IBaseInterface, which sounds like an abstract class (the "I" prefix was historically used for interfaces). You should probably rename your class so that it doesn't sound abstract. Also, the "I" prefix is redundant with the "Interface" suffix.

However, in what I consider "good" OOP, users do not need to know that you are handing them an interface. There is thus no need for a naming convention that differentiates concrete from abstract classes.

**3. Ownership semantics**

Shared pointers are meant for shared **ownership**: when you return a shared pointer, you are telling the users of your class that they will own the returned object, too. Usually, that is not needed. In most cases you would return a non-owning pointer, a.k.a. raw pointer. For example:

```
IBaseInterface* getInterface()
{
    return m_spBase.get(); // Instantiation done elsewhere, for example in constructor
}
```

**4. Slicing**

There is indeed slicing happening here. This line:

`m_spBase = std::make_shared<IBaseInterface>( m_derivedInterface );`

Actually expands to code that contains something equivalent to this:

`auto newInstance = new IBaseInterface(m_derivedInterface );`

In turn, the line above will call the copy constructor of the IBaseInterface class, whose signature is similar to:

`IBaseInterface(IBaseInterface& other)`

Thus, m_derivedInterface is interpreted as an IBaseInterface reference in the context of that call. Only the members of IBaseInterface will thus be copied during the call to "new", thereby losing all the information stored in the derived class, DerivedInterface.

---

All that said, it seems to me that what you really want is direct access to the m_derivedInterface object. What you are doing right now is, you copy the instance into another object and return the new object. I think what you really want is this:

```
IBaseInterface* getInterface()
{
    return &m_derivedInterface;
}
```

If you insist on using shared ownership, just store a shared pointer to m_derivedInterface instead of a value:

```
MyClass(Args args)
{
    m_derivedInterface.reset(new DerivedInterface(args));
}

std::shared_ptr<IBaseInterface> getInterface()
{
    return m_derivedInterface;
}

std::shared_ptr<IBaseInterface> m_derivedInterface;
```